# How to turn off output buffering in Apache Tomcat AccessValve

Tags: tomcat, logging

I have a Tomcat 6 server running, with access logs being written via an ExtendedAccessLogValve, and I noticed that it is buffering output. I was wondering if there is a way to turn off buffering for logs like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `buffered='false'` to your declaration.